# Bootstrap column help needed

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following Code, with 3 columns with col-md-4 the problem is that I want when the screen getting smaller to make all the col-md-4 text-right and text-left into text-centered.I searched everywhere but couldn't find help can you help??

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- first row -->
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="counter-item">
        <div>
          <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="CodeSchool! Click for more..">
            <img class="certification-image" src="images/codeschool.png">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
      <div class="counter-item">
        <div>
          <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title='Sololearn! Click for more..'>
            <img class="certification-image" src="images/sololearn.jpg" >
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
      <div class="counter-item">
        <div>
          <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Datacamp! Click for more..">
            <img class="certification-image" src="images/datacamp.jpg">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this at the end of last CSS file:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 767px){

    .col-md-4{
      text-align:center !important;
    }

}
```

Bootstrap 4 is in alpha release so many things can do not work properly.

Comment: Find info in google about media queries in CSS. You can set min-width and max-width to other values.

Comment: Using Bootstrap 4 is completely fine. You will not experience any major bugs that will break the typical grid, it's been alpha for over a year and a half. Many websites already use this in production.

Comment: I never use script that is in alpha or beta release ... and for sure not when I creating something for client or I have payments on site ... and if it's so long in alpha then they must have some problems

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with bootstrap 4. If you wish to do this in Bootsrap 3, you will have to create a custom class and attach it to a media query to get your desired results. I've created a quick CodePen example using Boostrap 4 for you: https://codepen.io/w7sang/pen/xrBNJG

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 text-center text-sm-left text-md-right">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 text-center text-sm-left text-md-right">
      B
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 text-center text-sm-left text-md-right">
      C
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow this helped a lot.. is there anything I can do to change the text-right/left to text-center exactly when the columns collapse and change rows??

Comment: @Zekelonas Yes, check my updated example :) Resize the window to see it change. Please mark as answer if it's sorted :D

Answer (score 0):

Add media screen

```
@media screen (max-width: 767px){

   .col-md-4{
        text-align:center !important;
    }

}
```

Bootstrap 4 Under Development mode release. That Why many things can't work properly.

You can use Stable Version of Bootstrap like 3